# Displaying a list using listview on a new activity. List depends on the button clicked

Tags: android, kotlin, android-listview

I have two buttons on my MainActivity. Both buttons open the same new activity but show a different listView depending on which one is clicked. I have been playing about with it and up to now I can get it to show on the MainActivity but can not figure out how get it so that it opens up on the second activity instead. I figure I need to somehow use the adapter in the new activity and then somehow pass the ListArray to it?? I have not been able to get it to work.

the code I have at the moment is that works is

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    lateinit var button: Button
    lateinit var button2: Button
    lateinit var test_list: ListView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        button = findViewById(R.id.button)
        button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2)
        button.setOnClickListener {

            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, ItemsList::class.java)

            test_list = findViewById(R.id.test_list)
            var breeds = arrayOf("")
            var breeds2 = arrayListOf<Breeds>()
            breeds2.add(Breeds("type1"))
            breeds2.add(Breeds("type2"))
            breeds2.add(Breeds("type3"))
            breeds2.add(Breeds("type4"))
            breeds2.add(Breeds("type5"))
            var adapter: MyAdapter
                adapter = MyAdapter(this, breeds2)

                test_list.adapter = adapter
                test_list.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
                    Log.d("Test list", breeds[position])
                    startActivity(intent)
            }

        }

        button2.setOnClickListener {

            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, ItemsList::class.java)

            test_list = findViewById(R.id.test_list)
            var breeds = arrayListOf("")
            var breeds2 = arrayListOf<Breeds>()
            breeds2.add(Breeds("breed1"))
            breeds2.add(Breeds("breed2"))
            breeds2.add(Breeds("breed3"))
            breeds2.add(Breeds("breed4"))
            breeds2.add(Breeds("breed5"))
            var adapter: MyAdapter
            adapter = MyAdapter(this,breeds2)

            test_list.adapter = adapter
            test_list.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
                Log.d("Test list", breeds[position])
               startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }
}


MyAdapter.kt

import android...

class MyAdapter(private val context: Context, private val dataSource :ArrayList<Breeds>) : BaseAdapter(){

    private val inflater: LayoutInflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)as LayoutInflater

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return dataSource.size
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        return dataSource[position]
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        var rowView:View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_items_list, parent, false)
        val textView : TextView = rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_name)
        textView.text = dataSource.get(position).breed
        return rowView
    }

}


breeds.kt

class Breeds {
    var breed : String =""

    constructor(breed: String) {
        this.breed = breed
    }
}

//I want to have the list view open up in this activity

ItemsList.kt

import...

class ItemsList : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_items_list)

    }
}

//my xml files are

activity_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button"

       />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/test_list"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

activity_items_list.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list_item_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/test_list"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could *technically* find a way to pass a list between two `Activity`s through an `Intent`, but passing objects starts to get a little complicated because there are a limited set of types you can put into a [`Bundle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle), and limitations on how much data you can pass

In this case, since you just have a list of `String`s, you could use the [`putExtra`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent?hl=en#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D)) method that takes a `String` array, and pull it out in the other activity:

```
// in first activity
intent.putExtra("list key", breeds2.toTypedArray())

// in second activity - could be missing (null result) so I'm using an empty default
val list = intent.getStringArrayExtra("list key")?.toList() ?: emptyList()
// now use it in your list adapter
```

But generally that's not a good idea. Ideally, your data (i.e. the lists) would be stored where *both Activities can access it*, and all you pass between Activities is some kind of ID, so Activity 2 can *fetch* the correct list. An easy way for this example is to just stick them in top-level `val`s that both Activities can see:

```
// this needs to be outside of both Activities - stick it in another file if you like
val list1 = listOf(Breed("breed1"), Breed("breed2")) // etc
val list2 = listOf(Breed("type1"), Breed("type2")) // etc

// button 1 listener:
intent.putExtra("list type", 1)

// button 2 listener:
intent.putExtra("list type", 2)


// in activity 2:
val listType = intent.getIntExtra("list type") // missing default is -1
val listToUse = if (listType == 1) list1 else list2 // simple either/or fallback
// use the list in your list adapter
```

but if your data can change (like modified lists), you'll need to be *persisting* that data, e.g. in `SharedPreferences`, a `DataStore`, or a database. You'd probably have another class that provides data, where your activities can request a particular list.

This isn't exactly how I'd organise the lists or fetch them, but hopefully that gives you the basic idea - store the data elsewhere in the app, and let activities pass simple identifiers so they can fetch a particular piece of data, rather than trying to pass entire data structures between activities